# How to handle callbacks in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, callback

Are there different callbacks available in asp.net like rails provide before_validation, before_update, before_save and before_destroy?

How to handle this scenarios in asp.net?

Comment: Does ASP.NET MVC have a base class from which all models are derived? If so, perhaps it wouldn't be too difficult to extend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the concept of Filters in ASP.NET MVC and also to the following 4 methods in the controller base class: OnActionExecuting, OnResultExecuting, OnAuthorization, and OnException.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting.aspx-

**Update**
On a second though I just realize that you might be looking for methods at the Model level and I answered from the Controller level. Unfortunately from what I understand that ASP.NET MVC does not provide as much at the Model level as Ruby On Rails does.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the link is broken so i'll pitch in.

### In MVC you would use Action Filters

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs

edit (I see you tagged as mvc but anyhow)

### In Web Forms the onLoad method is run before each page action

Using a base class can span it over multiple pages